# Generating a random ipaddress in C

Tags: c, random, windows, ip-address

I was looking to receive some feedback on the function I wrote to generate a random ip address. The code is pretty messy and just wanted some feedback regarding optimizations, memory leaks and best practices. I am aware that there are ip ranges that this could generate that don't actually exist but for my project it's fine if it generates non-existent local addresses.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int random_int(int limit) {
    HCRYPTPROV  crypt;
    byte *buf = (byte *)malloc(1);
    if (CryptAcquireContext(&crypt, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_SILENT)) {
        if (CryptGenRandom(crypt, sizeof(buf), buf)) {
            CryptReleaseContext(crypt, 0);
            return (int)buf % limit;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int num_places(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return num_places((n == INT_MIN) ? INT_MAX : -n);
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    return 1 + num_places(n / 10);
}

char* random_ip() {
    char* ip = (char*)malloc(1);
    int total_size = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int realloc_size = 0;
        int rand_num = random_int(255);
        realloc_size = num_places(rand_num);
        if (i != 3) {
            realloc_size++;
        }
        total_size += realloc_size;
        ip = realloc(ip, (total_size) * sizeof(char));
        char* str_ip = (char*)malloc(1);
        
        if (i == 3) {
            str_ip = (char*)realloc(str_ip, (realloc_size + 1) * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(str_ip, realloc_size + 1, "%d", rand_num);
        }
        else {
             str_ip = (char*)realloc(str_ip, (realloc_size + 1) * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(str_ip, realloc_size + 1, "%d.", rand_num);
        }
        ip[total_size - realloc_size  - 1] = '\0';
        strncat_s(ip, total_size, str_ip, realloc_size+1);
        free(str_ip);

    }
    return ip;
}

int main(){
   printf("GeneratedIpAddress: %s\n",random_ip()); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inet_ntoa` will convert a 32bit number into its corresponding IP address. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065584/convert-integer-value-to-ip-address

Comment: @chux not sure why I did that, thanks for catching that

Comment: @Skarlett Comments may be deleted. Please write all suggestions and observations about the code as answers, not comments, even if you aren't writing a comprehensive review.

Comment: @200_success I respect your work to fullest degree and find it honorable that your mission to create clear and decisive documentation related to the question, but observations lead me to believe that you either have failed mission, or disregarded your morals for truth. I find your rather destructive to remove commentary from someone who might be more experienced than you, and are unable to judge the value of it. 
Last I heard, the comment section was specifically for questions, and maybe an answer that is not structured, but does lead to documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bugs**

`return (int)buf % limit;` makes little sense to me.  Why take a pointer and form a "random" number from the *pointer*.

Perhaps you meant: `return buf[0] % limit;` to take the value of what the pointer points to.  Note that this `% limit` imparts a bias when `limit` is not a power-of-2.  It is 255 in OP's code.  OP, was it your intent to form values [0.. 254] (like this code does) or [0...255]?

`CryptGenRandom(crypt, sizeof(buf), buf)` is questionable too.  Why does `CryptGenRandom()` care to know the size of a pointer as with `sizeof(buf)`?  I'd expect `1` instead, the size of the allocation.

[`CryptGenRandom()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom) looks deprecated.

**Alternate digit counter**

Just a small idea alternative:  no recursion and no need for special handling of `INT_MIN`.

```
int num_places(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  do {
    count++;
    n /= 10;
  } while (n);
  return count;
}
```

**Allocate to the refenced object, not type**

Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Cast not needed either.

```
// str_ip = (char*)realloc(str_ip, (realloc_size + 1) * sizeof(char));
str_ip = realloc(str_ip, sizeof *str_ip * (realloc_size + 1u));
```

Better code checks for failed allocation

```
void *p = realloc(str_ip, sizeof *str_ip * (realloc_size + 1u));
if (p == NULL) Handle_Error();
str_ip  = p;
```

**Simplify allocation**

Code does a lot of work allocating and re-allocating.

Instead, form a local worst case size buffer, populate that and then allocate/duplicate it once at the end.

Rather than `strcat()`, keep track of the length.  Avoid [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm) code.

Simplify code with a variable separator.

No need for `num_places()`.

```
#define BYTE_AS_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE 3
#define IP_BUF_SIZE (4*(BYTE_AS_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE + 1))

char* random_ip() {
  char str_ip[IP_BUF_SIZE];
  int offset = 0;
  const char *separator = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    offset += sprintf(str_ip + offset, "%s%d", 
        separator, random_int(255) & 255);
    separator = ".";
  }
  return strdup(str_ip);
}
```

**Simplify random calls**

Rather than 4 calls to get 8 bits each time, consider 1 call to get 32 bits.

```
    uint32_t r = random_32();
    sprintf(str_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (r >> 24) & 255, (r >> 16) & 255,
        (r >> 8) & 255, (r >> 0) & 255);
```

**Return allocated data**

Better code explicitly frees allocated data.

```
int main(){
  const char *ip_addr = random_ip(); 
  if (ip_addr) { // add
    printf("GeneratedIpAddress: %s\n", ip_addr); 
    free(ip_addr); // add
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

**Alternate allocation**

Let caller provide the buffer.

```
//.h file
#define RANDOM_IP_SZ 16
char *random_ip(size_t sz, char buf[sz]);

// .c file
char *random_ip(size_t sz, char buf[sz]) {
  char local_buf[RANDOM_IP_SZ];

  // Form random IP in local_buf[]
  // ...

  if (strlen(local_buf) < sz) {
    return strcpy(buf, local_buf);
  }
  return NULL;  // Buffer too small
}
```

Comment: Should I have checks for every time I allocate memory? Also thank you for the feedback

Comment: @snowwindmir Recommend check every time, maybe through helper function: `void *realloc_or_exit(void *ptr, size_t n) { void *p = realloc(ptr, n); if (p == NULL)  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  return p; }`.

Comment: Thank you for the code review, this is helpful.